# Old movie with evil sorcerers transforming men into monsters

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic

I would like to know the name of a movie, which I saw a long time ago, when I was a child. I suppose I watched this about 1992

Production: (perhaps) '70s (language English, Hollywood (?))

Setting: Antiquity

Plot: The evil party in the film has sorcerers that use magic in order to transform captured men into beasts. More exactly:

They are brought into a cavern where the shamans perform a ritual, and I think some kind of alchemy is used. This makes their heads change into that of animals/monsters, whilst the rest stays human.

The protagonist almost falls victim to this magic/alchemy, but I don't think, that he gets transformed.

Answer (score 9):

**Atlantis, the Lost Continent (1961)**

This movie, directed and produced by George Pal, tells of a young fisherman from ancient Greece who rescues a princess of Atlantis. When he takes her to the fabled island kingdom, he is enslaved. A mad scientist in the House of Fear turns slaves into mindless beast-humans, but our hero avoids the fate.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantis,_the_Lost_Continent

It seems to fit: English language, before 1980, men transformed into beastmen, the hero escaping this fate. As can be seen in the poster below, the beastmen retain human bodies.

[image]